# Моделирования работы микропроцессора К580ИК80

Tags: c#

Мне нужно осуществить работу мп К580ИК80. Т.е. у меня будет ровно 55 шагов, для того, чтобы показать графически(анимация, тут ничего сложного нет) как данных идет через шину адреса в шину данных. Но также требуется, чтобы программа также передавала все эти данные через процессор ( в этом и проблема, подскажите как написать на С#?, с чего начать?)...

p.s. Про мп К580ИК80  и как он работает, уже начитался, принцип не сложен... Но хотелось бы понять как это описать в C#... вот [тут](http://www.computer-museum.ru/technlgy/i8080.php#cmdlist) , я читал про этот мп!

Вот [пример](http://www.kursovik.com/programming/271302.html) ПО.

Comment: Нда, помнится собирал в своё время компьютер, на базе этого микропроцессора, точнее на Zilog Z80, комп назывался ZX Spectrum, аж 48 кб доступного ОЗУ, а шина адреса адресовал 64 кб, 16 кб затенялось адресным пространством ПЗУ !

Comment: Не понял постановку задачи. Какая программа, что она делает, что за данные, в виде чего в программе должен быть представлен процессор. Как это программа относится к графической презентации? Каша.

Comment: добавил в пост пример...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общая идея такая (моделирование на уровне команд).

1. Регистры микропроцессора описываете как переменные.
2. Память системы - как массив байтов.
3. Цикл выборки-исполнения команд - как таблицу переходов.

Итого. В исходный массив записываете код программы. На каждом шаге выбираете данных. В таблице переходов выполняете действия соответствующие опкоду.

Если по приведенной вами ссылке есть готовый код, то перенести его на C# будет не сложно.

Comment: Спасибо, уже более имение представляю, что мне нужно делать)