# Представление мнемокода в С/С++

Tags: c, c++

Всем привет. Я интересовался у людей насчет моделирования работы мп [вот тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/82903/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA580%D0%B8%D0%BA80).

Хочется спросить у вас насчет мнемокода. Как его описать в процессе моделирования мп?

> Он предназначен для представления в удобном (мнемоническом) виде машинных кодов команд, обеспечивает эффективное использование ресурсов системы (процессор, память, периферия). Мнемокод используется в местах, где требуется быстродействие, ограничен по размер оперативной памяти. Ассемблером также называют иногда систему команд центрального процессора.

Посоветуйте мне что нибудь почитать о "оп коде"?

Comment: Собствнно к процессору мнемокод никак не относится. Но вывод в мнемокоде нужен будет, чтобы посмотреть код, находящийся в эмулируемой памяти. Для вывода нужно будет написать простейший дизассемблер. P.S. похоже автор цитаты под мнемокодом понимает инлайн-ассемблер:)

Comment: @insolor, Да а можете накидать ссылок про дизассемблер?? я буду в 1 раз его писать)... Просто курсач дали про моделирование мп. Сижу сейчас делаю... Не помню где уже цитату взял,да и не столь это важно :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По дизассемблированию информации очень мало. Разве что

- ["Тонкости Дизассемблирования (дизассемблирование в уме) Криса Касперски" (pdf)](http://kpnc.opennet.ru/DISASS.PDF) (это для x86, так что для 8086  многое из того что там написано не понадобится)
- Книга Пирогов В. "Ассемблер и дизассемблирование" глава "Формат команд микропроцессора Intel" (тоже для x86)

ну и инфа о формировании кодов команд: для [i8080](http://kaf401.rloc.ru/DSP/I8080_commands.htm) и для [i8086](http://www.mini-soft.ru/book/assem/glava6_1.php).

Дизассемблирование немного похоже на эмуляцию, только после распознавания команды идет не выполнение, а вывод мнемоники и операндов.

Comment: @insolor , а можно попросить вас скинуть толковых ссылок о мнемокоде и операндах? Буду устраивать трешь своему мозгу. Да и спасибо вам добрый человек за столь полезную инфу :)

Comment: Мнемокод - это просто замена числовых кодов операций на более удобные для запоминания человеком буквосочетания. Ссылки на то как по мнемонике получить код операции я уже дал, вам осталось только придумать как проводить обратную операцию:) Операнд - это то над чем производится операция, например регистр, число, адрес в памяти или номер порта ввода/вывода.

Comment: @insolor, Мде, ждите меня бессонные ночи. Ещё раз спасибо, что объяснили... пойду ковыряться в инфе.

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос, но раз речь зашла о дизассемблировании, то  [вот][1] крутой дизассемблер. Можно смотреть как мнемокод, так и машинные команды.


  [1]: http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3625386

Comment: @RomanoO, вопрос о написании своего эмулятора с простым дизассемблером.

Comment: В таком случае IDA должен оказать помощь.

Comment: @RomanoO, IDA здесь не поможет, здесь поможет конкретная информация по формированию кодов команд, которую я уже дал.

Answer (score 0):

А просто массив указателей на строки типа "mov", "ret", "jmp" где индекс элемента массива это КодОперации не годится ?

Comment: @avp,в коде команды часто содержится информация об операндах. Поэтому проще сделать не массив указателей на строки например с мовами со всеми-всеми вариантами операндов, а битовой маской отделить сам код операции от кодов операндов, а потом уже формировать строку.

Comment: А причем здесь операнды и формирование строки ? Разве в 8080 КОП не 1 байт в начале команды ? 

Берем его как (unsigned char) индекс к массиву указателей на мнемоноки опраций. Для всех несуществующих ссылка на строчку, скажем, "???".

Comment: [Система команд КР580ИК80А – i8080](http://kaf401.rloc.ru/DSP/I8080_commands.htm), рисунок 2. Там видно что в байте команды код операции (КОП) занимает от 2 до 8 бит. Кроме самого кода (в зависимости от команды) в этот байт могут входить например поля регистров-операндов.

Comment: Понял свою ошибку. Тогда придется анализировать эти биты и в конце концов получать индекс в массиве мнемоник.